# Как создать заголовок таблицы

Tags: javascript

Есть javascript функция:

```
function createthead(cols) {
    let Row = document.createElement('tr');
    if(cols === 2){
        Row.cells[0].innerHTML = "Name";
        Row.cells[0].id = "thName";
}
```

Не обращайте внимания на не совсем корректный синтаксис, просто всю функцию кидать не охота. Цель такая: создать строку хранящую заголовки столбцов таблицы, здесь один из заголовков пусть будет Name. При запуске кода в браузере выдаёт здесь ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`
Правильно ли я понимаю, что `undefined` так, как в Row ещё нет никаких ячеек? Если да, то как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял Вас, но если правильно, то:

```
function createthead(colNames) {

    let tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for(var i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++){

        let th = document.createElement('th');
        let colName = colNames[i];

        th.innerHTML = colName;
        th.id = "th_" + colName;

        tr.appendChild(th)
    }

    return tr;
}

console.log(createthead(['first','second']));
```